# How to get a value of a property in JSON array from extjs store?

Tags: json, extjs, store

I have been trying to dynamically generate a check box from a value which is in JSON array from a JSON store.

```
{"MODULECATOGERY":[{"Menu":"MSU"},{"Menu":"SCHEDULE"},{"Menu":"MARKET_DASHBOARD"},{"Menu":"FE_REFERENCE"},{"Menu":"QC_TOOLS"},{"Menu":"QUICKQC_VOICE"},{"Menu":"QUICKQC_DATA"},{"Menu":"MARKETQC_VOICE"},{"Menu":"MARKETQC_DATA"},{"Menu":"SURGERY"},{"Menu":"FILE_INVENTORY"},{"Menu":"MARKET_TRACKER"},{"Menu":"DRIVE_ROUTE_TRACKER"},{"Menu":"TICKETS"},{"Menu":"TICKET_TRACKER"},{"Menu":"ASSETS"},{"Menu":"METRICS"},{"Menu":"DAILY_STATUS"},{"Menu":"DAILY_PROCESSING"},{"Menu":"WEEKLY_WORKFLOW"},{"Menu":"CUSTOMER_QUESTIONS"},{"Menu":"KPI_PERFORMANCE_METRICS"},{"Menu":"COLLECTION_METRICS"},{"Menu":"OPERATIONS_DASHBOARD"},{"Menu":"PRODUCTION_DASHBOARD"},{"Menu":"SUPPORT_DASHBOARD"},{"Menu":"REVENUE_TRACKER"},{"Menu":"DEPLOYMENT_TRACKER"},{"Menu":"TICKETS"},{"Menu":"TICKET_TRACKER"},{"Menu":"ASSET_MANAGEMENT"},{"Menu":"GENERATE_SHIPMENT"},{"Menu":"SHIPMENT_TRACKER"},{"Menu":"RESOURCES"},{"Menu":"SCHEDULE"},{"Menu":"TRACKER"}]}
```

How can a get values associated with "Menu" in the above JSON.? If i can have each and every value into an array then i can dynamically assign these to generate a check box group.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi

Store.getRange() seems to be exactly what you are searching for. It will return you Ext.data.Record[] - array of records. If no arguments is passed, all the records are returned.

or use

var store = grid.getStore();
store.each(function(record,idx){
 //do whatever you want with the record 
 console.log(record.get('fieldName'); 
});

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate your store:

```
store.each(function(record) {
    var menu = record.get('Menu');
});
```

Edit: 
Since you're saying this doesn't work with dynamic data I think you iterate it before it has completed loading. To be sure to handle the iteration after the load you can do the following:

```
store.on({
    //Listener that fires everytime after your store has loaded
    load: function() {
        store.each(function(record) {
             var menu = record.get('Menu');
             //do stuff
        });
    }
});
store.load();
```

If you only want to execute the code the first time your store loads you can use the callback function on the `load()` method:

```
store.load(function() {
    store.each(function(record) {
        var menu = record.get('Menu');
        //do stuff
    });
});
```

Comment: The above solution work only with static data but not Dynamic data. Please help...

Comment: It does work with dynamic data. Be sure to iterate your store after it has loaded. I edited my post.